# Using Argparse without action parameters in python

Tags: xml, csv, python-2.7, command-line, argparse

Currently my program works as follows:

```
    argparse.py -i file.csv -o newfile.xml -x
```

where argparse.py is the name of the program and -i represents the input file which is file.csv and -o is what the output file is going to be which is called newfile.xml and -x is an action parameter that when called, converts the following csv file into an xml file. However, i am trying to edit my program so that on the command prompt, all you have to do is input:

```
    argparse.py file.csv newfile.xml
```

and it will automatically convert it into a xml file without -x or -i or -o. Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import csv
import indent
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

def get_args(args):
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert wordlist text files to various formats.', prog='Text Converter')
    parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='store_true',dest='verbose',help='Increases messages being printed to stdout')
    parser.add_argument('-c','--csv',action='store_true',dest='readcsv',help='Reads CSV file and converts to XML file with same name')
    parser.add_argument('-x','--xml',action='store_true',dest='toxml',help='Convert CSV to XML with different name')      
    parser.add_argument('inputfile',type=str,help='Name of file to be imported')
    parser.add_argument('outputfile',help='(optional) Output file name',nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not (args.toxml or args.readcsv):
        parser.error('No action requested')
        return None
    if args.outputfile is None:
        args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.xml'
    return args

def main(argv):
    args = get_args(argv[1:])
    if args is None:
        return 1
    inputfile = open(args.inputfile, 'r')
    outputfile = open(args.outputfile, 'w')
    reader = read_csv(inputfile)
    if args.verbose:
        print ('Verbose Selected')
    if args.toxml:
        if args.verbose:
            print ('Convert to XML Selected')
        generate_xml(reader, outputfile)
    if args.readcsv:
        if args.verbose:
            print ('Reading CSV file')
    return 1 # you probably want to return 0 on success

def read_csv(inputfile):
      return list(csv.reader(inputfile))

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)

    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    head.set('total_holes', '238')

    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
            if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
                toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})
                cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
        i+=1
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

i think maybe i should check for the position of each argument or something like that but how would i incorporate that as i am new to python

Answer (score 0):

You simply need

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('input_file')
p.add_argument('output_file')
args = p.parse_args()

# With read_csv and generate_xml defined as above
reader = read_csv(args.input_file)
generate_xml(reader, args.output_file)
```

Comment: but then i get another error at x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row which is a value error: need more than one value to unpack